# Reshaping a python list while keeping the order

Tags: python

If I have a python list with the shape like this:

```
T = [
['07,07,2012 22:10', ['people','drama','melody','bun']],
['08,07,2012 21:04', ['queen','group']],
['08,07,2012 21:23', ['printing','market','shopping']],
['08,07,2012 21:04', ['people','bun']],
['08,11,2012 11:14', ['kangaroo']]
]
```

What I need is to convert this list into this format:

```
T =[
['07,07,2012 22:10', 'people'],
['07,07,2012 22:10', 'drama'],
['07,07,2012 22:10', 'melody'],
['07,07,2012 22:10', 'bun'],
['08,07,2012 21:04', 'queen'],
['08,07,2012 21:04', 'group'],
['08,07,2012 21:23', 'printing'],
['08,07,2012 21:23', 'market'],
['08,07,2012 21:23', 'shopping'],
['08,07,2012 21:04', 'people'],
['08,07,2012 21:04', 'bun'],
[''08,11,2012 11:14'', 'kangaroo']
]
```

i.e. For each element having length of its first sub-element greater than 1 (in the original list T), split the first sub-element (`a[1] for a in T if len(a[1] > 1)`) and append it as another list with the same time stamp. Maybe my words lack the explanation, but the samples above are definitely explaining what I need to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

`[(timestamp, item) for timestamp, items in T for item in items]`

This will give you a list of tuples, which is probably suitable here. But you can modify it to get a list of lists:

`[[timestamp, item] for timestamp, items in T for item in items]`

Comment: Or use a list instead of a tuple to get exactly what the OP requested (shouldn't matter much, though).

Comment: Thanks @flornquake..you artistically summarized it all. Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this on T:

`def process(t):
    new = []
    for i in t:
        for j in i[1]:
            new.append([i[0], j])
    return new`

Comment: List comprehension will be faster and more pythonic.